# How do I find out which font is chosen by gnuplot when only specifying family?

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

I'm using the pngcairo terminal within gnuplot to produce images. Font is set to "sans,9" when specifying the terminal. How can I tell which specific font was picked for rendering?

terminal command:
    set terminal pngcairo font "sans,9" size 1500,1000

(edit) More info:
Installed under Windows 7 OS.
I just need to find what font was used for the given statement in gnuplot 4.4.4, which was used to create many plots. gnuplot 4.6.0 decides on a different font for the same statement, and it would be practically impossible to re-render all earlier plots to match.

Answer (score 4):

I created a file `test.gp`

```
set terminal pngcairo font "sans,9" size 1500,1000
set output "test.png"
plot sin(x)
```

Run gnuplot under `strace`

```
strace -o st.out gnuplot test.gp
```

grep

```
grep 'open.*/usr/share/font.*' st.out
```

gives me (`Linux  3.0.0-22-generic #36-Ubuntu`)

```
open("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 5
```

Comment: Wow.  Wouldn't have thought of that.  Nice answer. (+1 from me)

Comment: Any idea how to do this for a windows install?

Comment: @Parallax -- perhaps `straceNT` ( http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm )?  I've never used it, I just googled `strace for windows` and this is what I came up with.  Good luck.

Comment: straceNT doesn't seem to work with Windows 7. I tried looking through the installed fonts to find a match to what gnuplot is using, but no luck on the obvious ones. I'm going to just re-do the earlier plots while specifying the exact font, since it'll take less time than continuing to look for a solution. Should I mark this question as answered?